# Help with this problem involving a triangle

Tags: geometry, area, ratio

[image: Diagram of the problem]

The area of the triangle is 85 square centimetres, the side $AB$ is divided by the point $P$ so that the ratio $BP:AP$ is 1:4 and the side $AC$ is divided by $Q$ so that the ratio $AQ:CQ$ is 2:3. Find the area of $\triangle BXC$ and the ratios $BX:XQ$ and $CX:XP$.

I have found that $\triangle AQB$ = 34, $\triangle BXC$ = 68, $\triangle QCB$ = 51 and $\triangle PBC$ = 17. However, I cannot find a way to determine the area of $\triangle BXC$ with the information that I have found

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $CX:XP=s:(1-s)$.

$[\triangle BCP]=85\div 5=17$. Hence $[\triangle BXC]=17s$ and $[\triangle PXB]=17(1-s)$.

$\displaystyle [\triangle CPQ]=\frac{3}{5}[\triangle CAP]=\frac{3}{5}\times\frac{4}{5}\times85=\frac{204}{5}$.

$\displaystyle [\triangle QXP]=(1-s)[\triangle CPQ]=\frac{204(1-s)}{5}$.

$\displaystyle [\triangle BPQ]=\frac{1}{5}[\triangle BAQ]=\frac{1}{5}\times\frac{2}{5}\times 85=\frac{34}{5}$.

\begin{align*}
17(1-s)+\frac{204(1-s)}{5}&=\frac{34}{5}\\
s&=\frac{15}{17}
\end{align*}

$CX:XP=15:2$.

$\displaystyle [\triangle BXC]=17s=15$.

$\displaystyle [\triangle QXC]=85\times \frac{3}{5}-15=36$.

$BX:XQ=85:370=15:36=5:12$.

---

Alternatively, by Menelaus Theorem,

$\displaystyle \frac{BP}{PA}\times\frac{AC}{CQ}\times\frac{QX}{XB}=1$ and $\displaystyle \frac{CQ}{QA}\times\frac{AB}{BP}\times \frac{PX}{XC}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ladder theorem all these represented quantities are areas.

$$\frac{1}{\triangle ABC}+\frac{1}{\triangle XBC}=\frac{1}{\triangle PXB+\triangle XBC}+\frac{1}{\triangle XQC+ \triangle XBC}$$
$\triangle ABC=85$
$\triangle ABQ=34$
$\triangle CBQ=51$
$\triangle  APC = 17$
$\triangle PBC=68$

let the area of quadrilateral APXQ be $d$
$$ar. \triangle  PBX = \triangle  ABQ-d$$
$$ar. \triangle  XQC =\triangle  APC -d$$
$$ar. \triangle  PBX = 34-d$$
$$ar. \triangle  XQC = 17-d$$
Now plug in the values 
$$\frac{1}{85}+\frac{1}{\triangle XBC}=\frac{1}{34-d+\triangle XBC}+\frac{1}{17-d+ \triangle XBC}$$
one more equation can be formed i.e. 
$$\triangle ABC =d+34-d+17-d+\triangle XBC$$
$$ 14 +d=\triangle XBC$$
put this in above equation 
$$\frac{1}{14 +d}=\frac{1}{48}+\frac{1}{31 }-\frac{1}{85}$$
by solving $d=10.197$ and $\triangle XBC =24.197$

Answer (score 0):

Do the same problem for the triangle with vertices $A=(0,0)$, $B=(5,0)$, $C=(0,5)$ first. All relevant ratios will be the same.

By the way: It is unclear from the text whether $P$ is nearer to $A$ or to $B$; similarly for $Q$.